# jquery mobile div ui-grid content collapsing each other

Tags: android, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have created a dynamic jqm list elements append to the ul . the list looks like this

```
    var html_sec = $('<li data-theme=c><div class=ui-grid-b><div class=ui-block-a>
         <a class="ui-link-inherit" href="link.html"><img src="'
        +imageurl+
        '" /></a></div><div class=ui-block-b><a class="ui-link-inherit" href="'
        +link_url+
        '"><span>'
        +name+
        '</span></a><br /><a class="ui-link-inherit" href="'
        +link_url+
        '"><span>'
        +name2+
        '</span></a></div><div class=ui-block-c><a class="ui-link-inherit" href="'
        +link url+'"><img src="'
        +image_url+
        '" /></a></div></div></li>');
html_sec.appendTo('ul');
$("#list").listview("refresh");
```

as you can see the list contains 2 image and in middle two names added . the problem i am facing here is when i dynamically append these div the content

1.the names overlaps on the ui-block-c and 
2.images are not aligned in center of div and have to make them fit into the div

i tried most of basic css and jqm function it didn't work when i viewed it on the emulator .so what i have to do make these contents to be in the respective div's . Thanks in advance.

basically if its like this means the contents overlap on eachother in android mobile emulator

```
<div class="ui-grid-b">
   <div class="ui-block-a">asdfasdfadsfadfadfasdfadf</div>
   <div class="ui-block-b">asdfasdfadsfadfadfasdfadf</div>
   <div class="ui-block-c">asdfasdfadsfadfadfasdfadf</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to combine a listview with a gridview? Probably it helps, if you prepare an example how you would like to have it look like without adding the content dynamically...

Comment: @Taifun ya thats the basic idea . if there is a way to use some kind of padding or some other function to make content to fit into the div's.

Comment: I don't know why you need a gridview inside the listview... yes, your names overlap, but you could use <br> for new line, see example http://jsfiddle.net/eDBdP/

Comment: @Taifun coz i have to show list of elements with 2 images at both ends and their names at centre and i have separated the names with <br> u c.

Comment: As already mentioned: first prepare an example hardcoded (no dynamic elements) how you want everything look like. If that works, add the dynamic part as second step.